# Getting No of rows in Uniformgrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, uniformgrid

I have set uniformgrid as itemscontrol ItemsPanel.Havent set the no of rows or column.It adjusts according to the screensize.Now is it possible to get the no of rows?

Answer (score 0):

When you ask a question here on StackOverflow, you *really* should provide more information. Had you specified whether you wanted to access the number of rows in code behind or in a view model (the answers would be different), I'm guessing that you would have already received an answer.

I'm guessing that you want to access them in the code behind... for this method you'll need to implement this method:

```
public T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : 
DependencyObject
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i);
        if (child != null && child is T) return (T)child;
        else
        {
            T childOfChild = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
            if (childOfChild != null) return childOfChild;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then using this method:

```
UniformGrid uniformGrid = FindVisualChild<UniformGrid>(ItemsControl);
```

This example uses this XAML:

```
<ItemsControl Name="ItemsControl">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="3" Rows="2" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I dont want to set any specific no of rows or columsn in xaml.and sorry for not being thorough. I want to access it in code behind you got that right.I have created a custom ItemsControl and want to access its ItemsPanelTemplate which is uniformGrid and want to access the no of rows and column it dynamically sets.

Comment: No. cause I dont want to set no of columns and rows like you did <UniformGrid Columns="3" Rows="2">

Comment: So... *without setting the `Columns` and `Rows` properties*, does this `FindVisualChild` method do what you want?